# Access to IConfiguration in a dependency inverted class library

Tags: .net, appsettings

In VERY rough, I have built an architecture as follows in .net 8.0:

Monolith with Blazor server frontend which references an Application Layer class library this exposes various services to perform CRUD operations which the UI can call.

The data Access layer is in another class library which has a reference to the Application Layer, so basic dependency inversion of the Data Access Layer.

The Application Layer exposes interfaces for data access which the Data Access Layer implements.

The Data Persistence is via Dapper to a PostgreSQL database.

So, my question. I currently have hard coded the connection strings I use in the Data Access Layer for testing but I want them in App Settings in a connection string. How, in my Data Access Layer should I do this?

I can't seem to get the right pattern to get access to the App Settings in the UI root from the DAL  and not sure if I should do that or build an App Settings in the Data Access Layer which seems to be frowned upon, or I am missing something completely!

I have been frustrated by this one for a while now, any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.